# Displaying a note when focus comes over a text box

Tags: asp.net

I want to display a note to the user whenever the focus comes to a particular textbox i have written the note in a div and set its visibility to false what to do next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of your div, put that text into a ToolTip property on the textbox control and ASP.NET will take care of it for you.

Comment: actually i want to draw the attention of the user we will not expect the user to hover the mouse over it then read the tooltip